# Android Studio help in linking the fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I am new to android developing.I am done with how to navigate from fragment to fragment.Now I am little bit confused how to  navigate from fragment to activity.Can any one suggest me how to achieve that.

```
package com.example.sahilnitish.easyyagriculture;

    import android.app.Activity;

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.view.View;

    import android.widget.Button;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        boolean status=false;

        Button bn;

        @Override

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bn);

            bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     {
                @Override

                public void onClick(View v)

                {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    if(!status)
                    {
                        Fragmentone f1 =new Fragmentone();

                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.txt,f1);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        bn.setText("Mango");
                        status=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FragmentTwo f2 = new FragmentTwo();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.txt,f2);

                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        bn.setText("Go back");
                        status=false;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use intent to navigate from fragment to activity.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activityname.class);
    startActivity(i);
```